# automapper multi objects to one object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two sub class that I need to copy a List element from into a master object

```cs
public Class Foo1 : Anote
{
  public bool Ison { get; set;}
  public List<Anote>Anotes { get; private set;}

  public Foo1()
  {
    this.Anotes = new List<Anote>();
  }
}

public Class Foo2 : Bnote
{
  public bool Ison { get; set;}
  public List<Bnote>Anotes { get; private set;}

  public Foo2()
  {
    this.Anotes = new List<Bnote>();
  }
}

public Class Foo3 : Cnote
{
   public bool Ison { get; set;}
   public List<Cnote>Anotes { get; private set;}
   public List<Cnote>Bnotes { get; private set; }

}
```

I will be retreiving data from a database and putting this data into Foo1 and Foo2. I then need
to Map the List data from Foo1 and Foo2 into the List elements in Foo3.

I have done

```cs
Foo1A foo1a = new Foo1A();
Foo2A foo2a = new Foo2A();

Mapper.CreateMap<Foo1, Foo1A>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo2, Foo2A>();
Mapper.Map<Foo1, Foo2A>(foo1, foo1a);
Mapper.Map<Foo2, Foo2A>(foo2, foo2a);
```

and this works but what I need to do is

Map the List Anotes in Foo1 to the List Anotes in Foo3
  Map the List Anotes in Foo2 to the List Bnotes in Foo3.

Comment: duplicate question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413273/automapper-convert-from-multiple-sources

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should just be able to do:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<ANote, CNote>();

Mapper.CreateMap<Foo1, Foo3>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ANotes, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ANotes))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BNotes, opt => opt.Ignore());

Mapper.CreateMap<Foo2, Foo3>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BNotes, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ANotes))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ANotes, opt => opt.Ignore());

Foo3 foo3 = new Foo3();

Mapper.Map<Foo1, Foo3>(foo, foo3);
Mapper.Map<Foo2, Foo3>(foo2, foo3);
```

`foo3.ANotes` and `foo3.BNotes` should both have been mapped correctly.

Comment: For anyone else that stumbles upon this, I have been trying to use this solution to merge two lists of objects. I haven't been able to figure out how to get that to work. I had to use a foreach and then map each item and manually add it to a list.

Comment: @Icestorm0141: Do you have a new question open?

Comment: In second mapping Foo2 to Foo3, i.e., `.ForMember(dest => dest.BNotes, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ANotes))` shouldn't this `be src,BNotes` instead of `src.ANotes`?

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is you're duplicating the mappings for Foo1 and Foo2. If you have complicated mappings, duplicating that many is a code smell. I was hoping Automapper had a way to do this: `Mapper.CreateMap<Src1, Src2, Dest3>();` Like the OP, Src1 and Src2 are almost identical in structure.

Comment: In this example you are writing the lists into two different lists what if you wanted to write them all the to the same list in Foo3 ?  [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67833797/1841839)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't feel like an acceptable solution for my situation. I was falling asleep last night and had this thought:

Lets say you want to map your two classes, `Foo1` and `Foo2` to `Foo3`

```cs
public Class Foo1 : Anote
{
  public bool Ison { get; set;}
  public List<Anote>Anotes { get; private set;}

  public Foo1()
  {
    this.Anotes = new List<Anote>();
  }
}
```

+

```cs
public Class Foo2 : Bnote
{
  public bool Ison { get; set;}
  public List<Bnote>Anotes { get; private set;}

  public Foo2()
  {
    this.Anotes = new List<Bnote>();
  }
}
```

=

```cs
public Class Foo3 : Cnote
{
   public bool Ison { get; set;}
   public List<Cnote>Anotes { get; private set;}
   public List<Cnote>Bnotes { get; private set; }

}
```

All you really need is another wrapper class for Automapper purposes.

```cs
public class Foo1And2 {
    public Foo1 Foo1 {get;set;}
    public Foo2 Foo2 {get;set;}
}
```

And then define the mapping:

```cs
CreateMap<Foo1And2, Foo3>().ConvertUsing(x => ConvertFoo1And2ToFoo3(x));
```

```cs
public Foo3 ConvertFoo1And2ToFoo3(Foo1And2 foo1And2)
{
    return new Foo3
    {
        Ison = foo1And2.Foo1.Ison && foo1And2.Foo2.Ison,
        Anotes = foo1And2.Foo1.Anotes,
        Bnotes = foo1And2.Foo2.Bnotes,
    };
}
```

And use it

```cs
var foo3 = Map<Foo3>(new Foo1And2
{
    Foo1 = foo1,
    Foo2 = foo2,
});
```