# AutoMapper to join records from 2 tables into single IEnumerable viewmodel

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 Tables, say `T1` and `T2`. `T1` contains **oID,cID,date,status** and `T2` contains **cID,cName,cURL**. I have designed class for above 2 tables as below:

**T1.cs**

```
public class T1{
  public int oID{get;set;}
  public int cID{get;set;}
  public DateTime date{get;set;}
  public string status{get;set;}
}
```

**T2.cs**

```
public class T2{
    public int cID{get;set;}
    public string cName{get;set;}
    public string cURL{get;set;}

}
```

`cID` in `T1` is a `foreign key` referring `T2 - cID`

Now I have my `T3` view model as below to combine `T1` and `T2`

**T3.cs**

```
public class T3:T1
{
   public int cID{get;set;}
   public string cName{get;set;}
   public string cURL{get;set;}
}
```

`T3` extends `T1` and `T2` properties are defined in `T3`. Thus I was intending to combine 2 tables in a single view model using `AutoMapper`. I have below method to get all details from `T1` and related details from `T2`, which when filled will return `IEnumerable T3`.

```
public IEnumerable<T3> GetAll()
{
   var od = mycontext.t1repository.GetMany().ToList();
   var ck = myContext.t2repository.GetMany(x => od.All(y => y.cID == x.cID)).ToList();
   if (od.Any())
   {
        Mapper.CreateMap<tblT1, T3>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<tblT2, T3>()
                    .ForMember(x=>x.cID, a => a.MapFrom(s => s.cID))
        var response = Mapper.Map<List<T1>, List<T3>>(od);
        return response;
   }
   return null;
}
```

I tried the above code via **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413273/automapper-convert-from-multiple-sources)** but that is for single instance and I have to return `IEnumerable` of records. I am not sure how I can actually map data's from 2 table based on their `cID`. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to use fields from parent (T1) in T3?

Comment: @MegaTron Yes I do.. I need to display data from `T1` and its relevant data from `T2` and merge them in `T3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try something like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<T1, T3>();
    cfg.CreateMap<T2, T3>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var od = new List<T1> { ... };
var ck = new List<T2> { ... };

var result = od.Join(ck, t => t.cID, t => t.cID, (t1, t2) =>
{
    var t3 = mapper.Map<T1, T3>(t1);
    t3 = mapper.Map<T2, T3>(t2, t3);

    return t3;
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.. :) Thank you.. :)

Comment: I must add, that since am using **Automapper v4.0.4**, I had to do `Mapper.Initialize` instead of `var config=new MapperConfiguration`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: ohh sorry, that's true. I did it this way because I was using v4.2.1

Comment: Don't be sorry please.. I did not mention the version, so probably my mistake.. :) Happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

First you do not need here `cID` because it will be inherited from base class `T1`:

```
public class T3:T1
{
   public int cID{get;set;}  //need to remove
   public string cName{get;set;}
   public string cURL{get;set;}
}
```

Then create a map T1 to T3:

```
   Mapper.CreateMap<T1, T3>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.cName, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.cURL, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

After that create a map for T2 to T3:

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<T2>, T3>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.oID, opt => opt.Ignore())
   .ForMember(dest => dest.date, opt => opt.Ignore())
   .ForMember(dest => dest.status, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: Thanks for your time buddy.. I would like to go with above answer.. :) Good approach he has.. +1.. :)