# Issue in mapping Automapper configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, automapper-7

I have the following POCO classes:

```
public class Employees
{
    public int EmployeeId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int EmpImageId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string EmployeePhotoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string EmpAddress
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Images
{
    public int ImageId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ImgCode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int EmployeeId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int EmpImageId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string EmployeePhotoUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string EmpAddress
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

While getting the list of Employees present in the system, for each Employee, the photourl (EmployeePhotoUrl) is fetched from the Images table using the EmpImageId property.

```
// Get the list of Employees
var employees = await _dbContext.Employees
                    .Select(ef => new EmployeeDTO
                    {
                        EmployeeId= ef.EmployeeId,                        
                        EmployeePhotoUrl = images.FirstOrDefault(im => im.ImageId.Equals(ef.EmpImageId)).EmployeePhotoUrl,
                        EmpAddress = ef.EmpAddress

                    }).Skip((pageNo - 1) * 100).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```

I want to leverage Automapper in this case. The issue I see here is the assignment of EmployeePhotoUrl, since this property is fetched from another entity: Images

Can anyone help me to know how to leverage Automapper in this case.

Comment: You need to have the `Images` FK property in `Employee`.

Comment: Can you please help me with some code sample. Any help on this is much appreciated. I want to know how you are doing the mapping configuration.

Comment: I was talking about the EF entity, not AM.

Comment: `Employees` already has an `EmployeePhotoUrl`, is there any reason that one can't be used? Also `Skip((pageNo - 1) * 100).Take(pageSize)` might want to change the `100` to `pageSize`. That said, this question already addresses how to map from multiple sources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413273/automapper-convert-from-multiple-sources