# AutoMapper Mapping two objects, Second is Overwriting First's Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have tried this answer: [automapper multi objects to one object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429210/automapper-multi-objects-to-one-object/12433558#12433558). However, my second mapping `mapper.Map(additionalUploadSongViewModel, songs);` is still overwriting the other fields with default values, it is mapping `BuyLink` and `Lyrics` correctly though.

```
namespace App
{
    public static class AutoMapper
    {
        public static MapperConfiguration Config;

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            //Removed other mappings for verbose
            Config = new MapperConfiguration(x => {
                x.CreateMap<UploadSongViewModel, Song>()
                .IgnoreAllNonExisting()
                .ForMember(a => a.AudioName, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.SongName))
                .ForMember(a => a.AudioPath, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.SongPath));

                x.CreateMap<AdditionalUploadSongViewModel, Song>()
                .IgnoreAllNonExisting();
            });

            //No errors here
            Config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }
}
```

`IgnoreAllNonExisting()` is just an extension method that should ignore properties that aren't set in both models, I thought this would fix the problem but it hasn't.

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    foreach (var property in expression.TypeMap.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
    {
        expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
    return expression;
}
```

Domain Models:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Audio : Entity
{
    public string AudioName { get; set; }
    public string AudioPath { get; set; }
    public string CoverImagePath { get; set; }
}

public class Song : Audio
{
    //Removed some for verbose
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string Lyrics { get; set; }
    public string BuyLink { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModels:

```
public class UploadSongViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SongName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public string SongPath { get; set; }
    public string CoverImagePath { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalUploadSongViewModel
{
    public string BuyLink { get; set; }
    public string Lyrics { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadMusic(IList<UploadSongViewModel> uploadSongsViewModel, IList<AdditionalUploadSongViewModel> additionalUploadSongViewModel)
{
     //uploadSongViewModel and additionalUploadSongViewModel has all properties filled out properly here.

     IMapper mapper = AutoMapper.Config.CreateMapper();
     List<Song> songs = mapper.Map<List<UploadSongViewModel>, List<Song> (uploadSongsViewModel.ToList());

     //songs now have proper mapped properties from uploadSongsViewModel

     mapper.Map(additionalUploadSongViewModel, songs);

     //all songs properties (songName, artistName etc) have now been overwritten by additionalUploadSongViewModel properties, instead of only BuyLink and Lyrics.
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120042/automapper-creating-new-instance-rather-than-map-properties  .. this is a strange idea using two separate collections.. how do you even know that item 2 in collection 1 matches item 2 inc collection 2 every time?

Comment: @JamieD77 Thanks for the link. Seems like it's my problem.
I don't understand your follow up question though.

Comment: I was just wondering what would happen if `uploadSongsViewModel` has 10 items and `additionalUploadSongViewModel` only has 9..

Comment: @JamieD77 Ah. It can't. They each must have the same amount.

Comment: have you thought about just making `AdditionalUploadSongViewModel` a property of `UploadSongViewModel`?  Automapper can handle that

Comment: @JamieD77 Thanks! I hadn't. I'll try that